# Handling Authentication without a unique username or password

Tags: authentication, javascript, oauth

Working on a project and I have to authenticate a user that does not have a username ( '' ) or a password ( '' ).  There are users and guest_users, but a guest_user won't have to explicitly log-in, rather, they will be given a new user by POSTing to through our /api/ route that is set-up.

My question is, would OAuth / OAuth2 be useful for this?  Some introductory reading shows it as a way to verify access to a third-party application ( like signing in through Facebook ), but it has a secretKey, consumerKey, etc.  We could save the keys with the user and authenticate that way perhaps?

Is there another way?  We are currently looking into using Passport.js, but really the question is more in general.  We could even roll our own solution if OAuth is a little too 'heavy' for this, but we don't want a guest_user to easily be able to 'spoof' as another, simply by going off their word / unique ID

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oAuth has been designed to be able to authenticate a user against an external service (plus other extras like getting some useful information about that user form the authentication platform). So you would get the information you need.

This said, this is primarily an end-user construction, requiring an interactive session.

There are derived mechanisms like [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) which could work better in your case (since you mention `POST` and API I believe that there will be no interactivity).

But you could simply generate on demand unique tokens with a large entropy  and use them for persistent sessions (it is difficult to call that "authentication" as you do not have any challenge). This is basically a restricted usage of web cookies (you could leverage the libraries you already have to generate them).

Comment: Hey, marked this as correct.  A little bit before you posted I found a really nice library that I was able to use for my needs, and it used exactly what you talked about - So thanks for the confirmation.  Have a good day.

Comment: Thanks - what was the library you found?

Comment: Waterlock used in conjunction with SailsJS